# Plural translation strings not found when using QCoreApplication::translate()

Tags: qt, internationalization

When I declare a translatable string with **QCoreApplication::translate()** without plural, such as :

```
QCoreApplication::translate("Context", "[A] removed [B] item(s)");
```

the string is correctly detected my Qt5 Linguist after running lupdate.

When I declare the same string using plurals, such as :

```
QCoreApplication::translate("Context", "[A] removed %n item(s)", "", static_cast<int>(items));
```

the string is not detected anymore my lupdate.

This doesn't apply to the use of **tr()** calls, their plurals are correctly reported my lupdate.

Comment: Works fine for me with Qt5.15 and a simple main.cpp containing only an empty main and your QCoreApplication::translate() call.

Comment: @chehrlic You're right, the issue was the cast. I edited the question do add this important detail and posted the answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the **static_cast<>**.
Moving the cast to a separate line resolved the issue :

```
int itemsAsInt = static_cast<int>(items);
QCoreApplication::translate("Context", "[A] removed %n item(s)", "", itemsAsInt);
```